# Show OneNote page name in preview

Tags: sharepoint-online, onenote

I have an OneNote file that can be found by SharePoint if I search for a keyword. Is it possible to show the name of the OneNote page, where the keyword is located, in the preview?

Answer (score 0):

The location of OneNote Notebook in SharePoint Online environment is SiteAssets.

Example: https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/xxxx/SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx

We can't display The OneNote page, which is similar to a redirect feature.